# How to pass the object to action in slice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I need to pass `userId` and `userNickname` to action `authUser` in `authSlice` reducer.

authSlice:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
    userId : null,
    userNickame : "",
    isAuth : false,
    isAdmin : false, 
}

export const authSlice = createSlice({
    name : 'auth',
    initialState,
    reducers : {
        authUser : (state, action) => {
            //const {userId, userNickame} = action.payload;
            state.userId = userId;
            state.userNickame = userNickame;
            state.isAuth = true;
        },
    },
})

export const { authUser } = authSlice.actions
export default authSlice.reducer
```

calling dispatcher

```
//...

const dispatch = useDispatch();
const userId = useSelector((state) => state.userId);
const userNickname = useSelector((state) => state.userNickname);

//...

dispatch(authUser(/* I need to pass userId and userNickname here */));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply

`dispatch(authUser({ userId, userNickname }));`

which is equivalent to

`dispatch(authUser({ userId: userId, userNickname: userNickname }));`